# What is the contragredient representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V=M_2(\Bbb C)$ be the set of all $2$x$2$-matrices. Let $G=B$x$B$ where $B$ is the group of $2$x$2$ lower triangular matrices with non-zero diagonal entries. Then G acts on $V$ by $\rho (g,h)x=gx^th$ for $x \in V$ and $(g,h) \in G$. What is the representation $\rho^*$ of $G$ contragredient to $\rho$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll rewrite the formula for $\rho$ so that I find it more understandable (I know it is also somewhat accepted notation to write the "t" to the left, but in this case I first read it as "$x$ transposed"):
$$\rho(g,h)x=g x h^t.$$ (That is, $h$ is getting transposed).

The space $V$ has a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form defined by 
$$(x,y)=\mathrm{trace}(xy).$$ This form identifies $V$ with its dual. In terms of this identification, the dual ("contragredient") representation $\chi(g,h)$ is given by

$$\chi(g,h)(y)(x)=y(g^{-1} x (h^{-1})^t)=\mathrm{trace}(y g^{-1} x (h^{-1})^t)=\mathrm{trace}((h^{-1})^t y g^{-1} x)=((h^{-1})^t y g^{-1})(x).$$ In other words, 
$$\chi(g,h) y =(h^{-1})^t y g^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks Steve. In my case the bilinear form that is being used to identify $V$ with $V^*$ is $tr(xy^l)$ where $y^l=dety (y^{-1})^t$. With this bilinear form and using your solution above we get $\rho(g,h)x=(detgdeth)^{-1}\rho(h,g)$ which is what I was trying to get.